# Any Node.js Minifier supports Javascript Null-Coalescing operator (??)?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am trying to minify javascript code, which contains many instances of the null-coalescing operator (??), however they all seem to throw `Unexpected token: operator (?)` error when parsing lines containing the ?? operator. Is there any updated library that works? I have tried the following:

```
gulp-uglify-es
terser
gulp-uglify
gulp-uglifyes
```

Comment: I am having this exact issue is there any update?